# How to move In stock/Out of Stock availability up and remove 2nd price in Magento

Tags: php, magento

On my product page I have a price showing twice and the out of stock/in stock message showing in an odd place.

I want to remove the 2nd price and move the availability into the "product-options-bottom" div.

The product options are in default.phtml and are not being referenced in view.phtml at least not that I see, I'm new to Magento. How would I go about moving where it gets placed on the page?

Lastly I'm not sure where or why that 2nd set of pricing is showing up and have no idea how to remove it.

Code:
[image]
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Price and Stock message are being rendered in product/view.phtml by the call

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
```

you can find a call to price in the template that has the stock messages in product/view/type/default.phml you could remove it from there if you can't figure out why the other one is showing up.

To figure out where things are in Magento use the template path hints by going to System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer and then change the store view to whatever you need and there will be three drop downs under the Debug tab. Change the bottom two to "yes" and refresh your site.

Another way to figure out where things are is moving things around in the template, change the order of the php calls or delete them temporarily and see what happens.